# Как сделать раскрывающееся на всю страницу меню?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как сделать меню как на изображении? При нажатии на бургер должен появится фон на всю страницу как на изображении и меню. Как такое можно реализовать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://codepen.io/jlnljn/pen/LkXoBb

Answer (score 3):

Например, так:

```js
$('.nav__icon').click(function() {
  if ($('.main').is(':visible')) {
    $('.main').slideUp('slow');
    $('.nav__icon').removeClass("active");
  } else {
    $('.main').each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay((i++) * 800).animate({
        height: "show"
      }, 800);
    });
    $('.nav__icon').addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrp {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 50px;
  min-height: 1000px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 50px 0;
}

.main {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 100px 0 0 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul.main__list {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.main__list li {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.main a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main a:hover {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.main__social {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.main__social li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px 3px auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.main__social a {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.nav__icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  top: 18px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 29px;
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.nav__icon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

.nav__icon span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

.nav__icon span:nth-child(2),
.nav__icon span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 10px;
}

.nav__icon span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 20px;
}

.nav__icon.active span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 10px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

.nav__icon.active span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav__icon.active span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav__icon.active span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 10px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrp">
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <p>Очень много текста</p>
  <div id="main" class="main">
    <ul class="main__list">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="main__social">
      <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nav__icon"><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
```